# Is it possible to report an activity date and calculate which pay period it falls under in a bi-weekly schedule

Tags: calculated-column, validation, calculated-column-formula

I really have no idea how to address this. I am tasked with marking and developing a way to track late entries based on the created date of a list item, the reported activity date(date selector), and the bi-weekly due date(every other sunday/Somehow needs to be calculated - Not sure how to reference this date). 
My logic is if the activity reported date is within the correct bi-weekly due date (> smaller due date and < bigger bi-weekly date) and the created date is > the bi-weekly due date that activity is reported in; it is considered late.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workflow that fires when an item is created should work for this. Just run the conditions using if statements and send an e-mail if it's late.

Comment: Oh, and this should help in order to calculate the every second sunday thing. http://nishon.blogspot.ca/2013/06/get-day-of-week-in-sharepoint-2010.html